# Include order of forward headers with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format has `IncludeIsMainRegex` to determine if several files share the same *main header*, in order to place this `#include` directive first. Neat enough.

I almost always use forward declaration headers of this style: "entity_fwd.hpp", "entity.hpp", and "entity.cpp". Additionally also an "entity_test.cpp", which should use the "entity.hpp" header. "entity.hpp", however, should use "entity_fwd.hpp" as its *main header*.

So, what I actually need is a way to specify additional headers as *main*, instead of additional source files using the same *main header*.

Has anyone found a way to make clang-format do this?

**EDIT:**
OK, so a little more context. Suppose I have this header, called `entity_fwd.hpp`:

```
class Entity;
class Player;
class MOB;

bool collisionTest(Entity const & e1, Entity const & e2);
```

I then have a normal definition header, `entity.hpp`:

```
#include "entity_fwd.hpp"
#include "world.hpp"
#include <vector>

class Entity {
public:
    Entity(Entity const &) = delete;
    virtual bool isAlive() const;
    ...
};

...
```

And finally an implementation file, `entity.cpp`:

```
#include "entity.hpp"

bool collisionTest(Entity const & e1, Entity const & e2) {
    ...
}

bool Entity::isAlive() const {
    ...
}

...
```

For `entity.cpp` clang-format *knows* that `entity.hpp` is the *main header* for that file, based on the stem of the header's filename; the term *main header* is clang-format's terminology. The *main header* will be placed first in the list of includes.

For `entity.hpp` the *main header* should be `entity_fwd.hpp`. I can use `IncludeCategories` with a regex `'_fwd.h(pp)?"$'` to sort `entity_fwd.hpp` first, but that will place *all* `_fwd` headers first, where only `entity_fwd.hpp` should get special treatment.

Comment: I have some trouble following this question. What is called *main* header in this context? Example with "entity_fwd.hpp", "entity.hpp" does not clarify much, it makes no sense to place one include directive first because they should not appear both at the same file.

Comment: @VTT Right. I've added more context to the question. Maybe it was a bit sparse. Note that my "issue" is purely clang-format related; I do know how to use forward-declaration headers. :-)

Comment: Now it seems to me that this whole idea of placing *main* header first is wrong. It is mandatory that the first header placed is a precompiled header, followed by a project configuration header (unless they are not used or included though different method) while I don't see any reason to place *main* header at the leading position. Typically even if I forced to put implementation into .cpp file I would list header declaring stuff that is going to be implemented in this file among other local headers in the alphabetical order.

Comment: @VTT My preference is to start specific and go general. Hence I have the "main" header first, project-specific headers next, then third-party libraries and finally standard library headers. This also has the "advantage" if you will, of determining if any headers are not self-sufficient. YMMV.

Comment: [Placing *main* header first does not really have an advantage of determining if any headers are not self-sufficient.](https://gist.github.com/guaranteed-to-be-unique/7ef1199cac89bf02d412fbd50f1e5ebd). Actually I can't think of any 100% working approach to determine whether header is self-sufficient or not (including only that header maybe if no preprocessor is involved?). Not giving main header special treatment would probably be more helpful regarding this matter. At lest with alphabetical sorted headers of the same location behavior will be consistent across different translation units.

Comment: @VTT No, there is indeed no 100% guarantee. Anyway, we're getting away from the point here, which is about the clang-format configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for `clang-format` shows a new style option `IncludeIsMainSourceRegex`, which appears to be what you need. This isn't in version 10.0.0, so you'll need to find a `clang-format` version newer than that.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be exactly what the doctor ordered. :-) I was just a few iterations too early out...

Comment: But how did you actually solve it? What was the regex for IncludeIsMainSourceRegex?

Comment: I don't have a new enough `clang-format` to verify, but based on the documentation I would guess something like (_fwd\.hpp)$

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I believe the answer is "no, this is not possible, and won't be any time soon".  As far as I can tell, the clang-format designers have made a core assumption in designing these options, which unfortunately categorically excludes the `_fwd.hh` pattern.

The answer from @eric-backus gives half of the solution.  It shows that clang-format has a new option, `IncludeIsMainSourceRegex`, which lets you expand your notion of which files are eligible to have a "main" include file.  That's a good start!

The problem is that the second half of the solution is impossible.  `IncludeIsMainRegex` lets you "specify a regular expression of suffixes that are allowed in the file-to-main-include mapping".  Note that these are suffixes **for the file itself**.  What we need to be able to specify is a suffix **for the included file**.  The only way that could ever happen is if clang-format adds a brand new option with new semantics.

---

So, what *can* you do?  The best solution I've found is to simply add a comment on the line **after** your main include.  It's more economical than a `// clang-format off` and `// clang-format on` pair, and it communicates the intent.  Hopefully someday clang-format will make this workaround obsolete.

```cpp
#include "entity_fwd.hpp"
// _fwd.hpp

#include "world.hpp"
#include <vector>
```

---

(By the way: why did they even add the new option, if it doesn't help with this?  My understanding is that it lets you handle the case where "foo.hh" should be the first include of "foo_impl.hh".)